# What are the disadvantages/advantages of having a container for each document type in cosmosdb?

Tags: database, azure-cosmosdb

I am designing a cosmos DB database, I have kept all the different document types in a single container and added a `type` property to differentiate the document types. I know a few advantages of this approach of database modeling-

- Low costing
- Transaction support with in the same partition documents

Now my superior who comes from SQL land wants me to have containers for each type of documents. But I do not know what is the advantage or disadvantage of that approach? I tried searching but anywhere it is not answered clearly. Also, like to know what is the disadvantage of my approach.

Answer (score 3):

There is ZERO advantage for doing this and is an anti-pattern for this type of database. Data in a NoSQL data store should be organized around how it is accessed. Normalizing to optimize around storage made sense 50 years ago when relational databases first appeared. But today, storage is cheap compared to compute.

Simple rule of thumb. If different entities can naturally share the same partition key, store it in the same container, especially if the data needs to be accessed in same request. This reduces cost to access because you can access all the data you need in a single request (query). If the data was stored in multiple containers you need to make a request to each container. This is both slow and expensive.

There is lots of content that explains these concepts and why you do not use Cosmos DB like a relational database. I strongly suggest your superior take a look at the links below. It is extremely important to understand these concepts before using a database like Cosmos DB.

[Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)

[How to model and partition data on Azure Cosmos DB using a real-world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Ignite 2019 Session [Data modelling and partitioning in Azure Cosmos DB: What every relational database user needs to know](https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/79932)

Comment: Are there any performance impact if one of the entities which share partition key has a lot more data in a partition. Are there any inherent bottleneck with this approach when the system scales.

Comment: A key aspect to partitioning is that data (and requests) should be spread across partitions as evenly as possible. Throughput in Cosmos is evenly allocated across partitions so if you have one partition with a lot of data (aka hot partition) and others with very little you are not running optimally. Can read more here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview

Comment: I mean a single type of document in all the partition has more data than other types.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't matter.

Comment: How about indexing policy, when it could be different for different document types?

Comment: @CharlesPrakashDasari, also doesn't matter. You can add any arbitrary set of key-value pairs for indexing. Although defining specific properties to index is itself an anti-pattern. The best method is to define properties NOT to index. Then any changes or new document types added to the collection are automatically indexed without having to rebuild it.

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant. I could imagine different types of objects having different properties that we would want to skip from indexing. Seems that since there is one indexing policy per container, properties from each document type that shouldn't be indexed have to be specified explicitly in the policy.

Comment: i would not use the indexing policy as a reason to not store different entities in the same container. The rule of thumb and a best practice is that if the data is accessed frequently together and they share the same partition key, then store the different entities in the same container.